# Parse Dashboard on AWS and adding cloud code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, parse-server

I configured a parse server on my AWS elastic beanstalk using [this guid](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxCD57GZLM2JR/How-to-set-up-Parse-Server-on-AWS-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk) I've tested it and it all works fine
Now I can't find a way to deploy parse dashboard on my server.
I did [deployed parse dashboard](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard) on my local host and connected it to the application on server, But this way I cannot manage (Add and remove) my apps.
Another problem is that parse dashboard missing cloud code on default, I found [this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/895) on git, but I cant understand where do I add the requested endpoints, is it something like adding `app.use('/scripts', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/scripts')));` on the index.js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to deploy parse-dashboard to your EC2 you need to follow the **Deploying Parse Dashboard** section in parse-dashboard github page

[parse-dashbard github page](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard)

Please make sure that when you deploy parse-dashboard you are using https and also basic authentication (it is also part of the guide)

Now regarding the cloud code: the ability to deploy cloud code via parse CLI and to view the nodejs code in parse dashboard are not available in parse-server but those are parse.com features. Cloud code in parse-server is handled by modifying the main.js file which exist under the cloud folder and deployment should be done manually by you but the big advantage in parse-server cloud code is that you can use any NodeJS module that you want from there and you are not restricted to the modules that were used by parse.com .

Another point about the dashboard. What you can do is to create an express application and then add parse-server and parse-dashboard as a middleware to your express application and deploy the whole application to AWS and then you can enjoy both parse-server (that will be available under the /parse path, unless you changed it to something else) and parse dashboard that will be available under the /dashboard path

Enjoy :)

Comment: Tnx, I did follow the github page guid, but it describes only Local Installation, So i installed it locally and used the `parse-dashboard-config.json` to point to my server. However i couldn't understand how to open up the propper endpoints to enable cloud code according to [this guid](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/895)

Comment: Hi @ItayAmza from what i understand those endpoints needs to be implemented by parse-server it's not enough just to open them (BTW! you can open endpoints via app.use) so i think we should wait until it will be available..